# one function or many for doing two-way lookups on multi-column junction table?

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server, we have a junction table associating our property IDs with IDs (text or numeric) of the same properties in several external databases (with sentinel value -1 or '-1' for no link):

```
SEPID    SEPCODE   AEID     MRIID    ABSID  PEDID
 2087   '140800'  26077  '140800'     '-1'   3162
 2088   '140900'     -1  '140900'     '-1'   3167 
 2089   'F21610'  25744      '-1'     '-1'   3184
 2090    '15402'     -1      '-1'     '-1'   3185
 2094   '141200'  26085  '141200'  '83296'   3198
```

As databases and business needs grow, we write new specific functions to translate one set of IDs to another, taking a comma-separated string list of input IDs and returning either a table of output IDs or another comma-separated list of output IDs, with different use cases for the table-valued (TVF) vs scalar-valued (SVF) functions. For example (using hard-coded rather than the normal programmatically-managed ID lists):

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.tvf_SepIdsToAbsIds('2088,2090,2094')
SELECT * FROM dbo.tvf_MriInfo(dbo.svf_AeIds2MriIds('26077,25744'))
```

would return:

```
ABSID
'-1'
'-1'
'83296'
```

and

```
MRIID     NAME    ETC...
'140800'  'Foo'   ...
```

I'm wondering if there is a sensible, practical, reasonably performant way to replace these proliferating specific functions with a single generic TVF and SVF that would take two column names and a list of IDs:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.tvf_Ids('SEPID', '2088,2090,2094', 'ABSID')
SELECT * FROM dbo.MriInfo(dbo.svf_Ids('AEID', '26077,25744', 'MRIID'))
```

Is it possible? Does it require dynamic SQL? Do the sometimes-text/sometimes-numeric external IDs complicate things greatly? Is it worth the struggle? Dynamic SQL always feels a bit dodgy and in this case I'm not even sure how to write it.

Comment: I cringe that you have lots of processes passing around csv values. Table valued parameters would be better but this also sounds like it might be cross database. For splitting strings look here. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: Instead of making your process more complicated and slower maybe you should consider making your process simpler and faster.  For example isn't `SELECT ABSID FROM transtable WHERE SEPID IN (2088,2090,2094)` Simpler and better than your first example?

Comment: @Sean: I think I've got the string-splitting down as well as it can be; I'm aware of the unsavory nature of it, but until we update our SQL Server it's my (mis?)understanding that it's my best option? Would appreciate a link to a discussion of a better way that works nicely with, at least, an ASP.NET front-end. I'm not doing any cross-database; I get periodic dumps into local tables of property values from the external databases.

Comment: @Hogan: so how am I to generate these non-string ID lists and pass them around b/n the DB and front-end, and within the DB? And if I want to make it generic so I can convert b/n arbitrary ID columns in my table, how do I do that, and deal also with the sometimes numeric/sometimes text IDs? Maybe I'm missing the forest for the trees here...?

Comment: Then you should look at using table valued parameters. You can send and receive those as DataTables from dotnet.

Comment: How do you generate and pass stuff now.  Everything in the string I put in my comment is in the string you had in your example.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question you have a number of databases each mastering a set of IDs. In you chosen database you relate some\all of these with local data. You then want a way of translating between the local\remote IDS.

You could use Synonyms to point to the database and then a view to consume your synonym.

So you would have

```
Select *
from MyNewView
```

and in your MyNewView

```
Select *
from MyNewSynonym s
inner join Mytable.ABSID = s.ABSID
```

Your local data just looks at the view and doesn't know anything about the different databases or any particular conversion issues. Its all hidden in the Synonym and view.

Not really sure why you are using TVFs but they are better than using SVFs which you definitely want to avoid for performance reasons. Even better if you can hide it in a view as it may give you indexing advantages.

As for splitting strings and converting them to a rowset, you can use a number of methods to do this. Including a TVF, CLR function or some horrid looping. There a number of examples to assist out there. You then just join the result in with the results from your view above.

Comment: Thanks. I may not be following you. What I'm trying to achieve is translation between *arbitrary pairs* of IDs. I've got everything in one table, but if I have a set of, say, AEIDs I may need to get the corresponding set of SEPCODEs, or MRIIDs, or whatever... different contexts involve different pairs of ID columns. I'm not seeing how your suggestion gets me "generic" pairing; right now, I'm not doing it generically -- I'm writing a new TVF (or SVF) for each unique "from" and "to" ID pair.

Comment: As for why I'm using functions, perhaps due to ignorance? There are LOTS of properties (thousands, 10's of thousands) but generally I only need a few (10's); I've been using joins on the TVFs to select only those records of interest. If I use views instead, I'd have to find a (generic?) way to write WHERE clauses for each possible set of input IDs, wouldn't I?